# Bootstrap Nav Bar Megamenu dropdown not working

Tags: bootstrap-4, nav

Below code for my navbar but the drop down not showing when I click For Techies.
I'm not getting error so i'm not sure what the issue is. Please help!!!!
Also how do i get it to show when it's hovered rather than when clicked?
Thanks!

```
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav" aria-controls="mainNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Navbar Brand</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-fill">

      <li class="nav-item px-4">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item px-4 dropdown">
       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="servicesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">For Techies</a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="servicesDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Get a Mentor</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">How we fit your needs</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <div class="d-md-flex align-items-start justify-content-start">
         <div>   
          <div class="dropdown-header">Positions</div>
          We are seeking developers, designers,  wih diverse set of technical skills, 
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Developers</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> UX/UI Designers </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">DevOps </a>
         </div>
         <div>
          <div class="dropdown-header">Professional Services</div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project rescue</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Source code recovery</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Application support &amp; maintenance</a>
         </div>
         <div>
          <div class="dropdown-header">Fixed Price Services</div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add cookie consent</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add captcha</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add core data</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Custom error pages</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact form creation</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Automated backups</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image to HTML</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-4">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-4">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a guide:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Utilities
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="developer.html">developer</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="programmer.html">programmer</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="menubar.html">menubar</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="testing.html">testing</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="product.html">product</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="service.html"> services</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="about.html">about</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Its in my archives that I used to create dropdown